# Restore Text Selection from a Range

Tags: angularjs, rangy

I have a range object created by Rangy in Javascript. Now i want to Restore the text from this Range object.

E.g range= WrappedRange {nativeRange: Range, commonAncestorContainer: div.ng-scope, collapsed: false, endOffset: 19, endContainer: text…}

Need help with how can i do it ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need

```
var sel = rangy.getSelection();
sel.setSingleRange(range);
```